# Missing Google Cloud Container Image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to solve a tutorial from the Google cloud platform, "[Detecting anomalies in financial transactions by using AI Platform, Dataflow, and BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/detecting-anomalies-in-financial-transactions)"
But, the docker image required to run the data pipeline is not available in the Google Cloud Container Registry.

[image]

The link to the image was [this](https://gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/df-ml-finserv-anomaly-detection) as provided in the tutorial github repo.
But, when triggering the pipeline, it shows the following error.

[image]

Comment: From the first image, it seems like you have not selected the project. Can you select your project from the drop-down button and try again?

Comment: @kiranmathew I tried selecting the project but it still shows me the same error.

Comment: Only the project owner or the persons who has appropriate permission can see the contents in the project. BTW, where does Container Registry appear in the blog you shared? I read through the document but cannot find any words such as Container Registry or Docker. Can you paste the excerpt of Google Cloud document? Otherwise I cannot help you.

Comment: @RyoMatsuzaka It is used a the template-file-gcs-location parameter value while triggering the data pipeline. https://cloud.google.com/architecture/detecting-anomalies-in-financial-transactions#run-pipeline

Comment: Ok, I will check it.

Comment: You are right I got `docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied` error.

Comment: We cannot solve the issue now so I asked it here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/df-ml-anomaly-detection/issues/23 and did document feedback to google cloud.

Comment: @R.Maharjan Does this [troubleshoot article](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/troubleshoot) by Google help you to solve your problem. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: The provided template/image does not exist anymore. You are going to have to rebuild it from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/df-ml-anomaly-detection or try to get someone to do it for you on that repository.